# flutter: Release mode is different in everything from debug mode, even icons aren't showing

Tags: flutter, debugging, apk, release

application looks different in release mode; it doesn't have any icons and widgets seem to grow bigger, fonts are different

commands used:
flutter build apk --build-name=1.0 --build-number=1

flutter run --release

I was trying to test release apk but it was totally different.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the default fonts and icons or are you using an external package like `google_fonts` or `font_awesome_flutter`? Check if you have in your pubspec.yaml `uses-material-design: true`

Comment: default icons 
this is my pubspec

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YVDFFJnX9qM3SvZUOhn4LtKxClhUCju1?usp=share_link

Comment: it also has My build log and my log cat

Comment: for fonts i use font family named Cairo, added it in the pubspec as u can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after 3 months of searching. It turned out that the font I used messed with the icons. Not sure how or why but the font I added in pubspec from Google fonts named Cairo was buggy. I recommend not using it.

Once I removed it everything came back to normal again!